# Can I close my door with a torch?

Tags: photons, pressure, laser, radiation-pressure

[Photon pressure](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/R/Radiation+Pressure) is definitely one of the most amazing phenomenon that I have heard in a while.

**Some examples:**

1. The pressure from the [photons emitted by the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure#Solar_radiation_pressure) can perturb the motion of artificial satellites as the momentum is exchanged creating a perturbing force.
2. The [Space Environment Research Centre](http://www.serc.org.au/) in Australia intend to use high powered lasers to perturb the orbit of space debris, sending space junk in to our atmosphere with the intention that it will burn up!

**Question**

It has most certainly happened to everyone in the community where you've gone to bed only to realise that you've forgot to close the door. On a much smaller scale, yet equally as annoying as space debris.

What would be the magnitude of photon pressure required to cause a force big enough to close a bedroom door?

Comment: Photon pressure isn't any different from mechanical pressure: what is the pressure that you need to close your bedroom door, assuming a certain active area? Then, compute the power that should have your torch ;-)

Comment: Scary stuff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky_effect.   Nearly as scary as how lazy some people can be :)

Comment: I think the sun doesnt exert much photon pressure, the solar flares that are emitted are burst of ultraviolet radiations, that disturb the magnetosphere and the information transmitted by satellites.

Comment: Scale, scale, scale. Because the relationship between impulse $J$ and power  $P$ for optical transfer is quite simple ($P = cJ$ with $c$ the speed of light) and the speed of light is a *big* number, you should be able to deduce the effect that enough light to cause the swing would have on the door without a lot of computation. Mirroring the surface will increase the impulse while reducing the thermal load, but because of the limits of achievable reflectivities even that won't be enough.